# User input function C

Tags: c, input, stdin

### User input function C

Hi all! I've got a problem with reading user input from a console. I am trying to implement function that reads and allocates memory from the console in chunks.

### First issue

First issue is I am getting some artifacts at the beginning of the output. For an input:

> Sample input 1

> Sample input 2

> Sample input 3

> Sample input 123

I get:

> ­_←Sample input 1

> _♂Sample input 2

> _|Sample input 3

> _ľSample input 123

In debugger `char buffer[block_size];` variable looks fine, after `fgets(buffer, block_size, stdin) != NULL` is executed.
and I think that problem occurs in `strcat(input, buffer);`. I have no idea why it does that. My guess I am allocating/reallocating memory wrong.

### Second issue

Second issue is that console outputs maximum of 4091 characters on **Windows**, with artifacts at the beginning. I have tried inputs like 5000 or 8000 'a' characters.

Is it possible to increase the input without overcomplicating my code?

### Additional information

I'm using Windows 10 Pro, Version: 10.0.19044 Build 19044.

Clion IDE.

MinGW toolset.

C11 standard.

On Linux Mint machine I do not get artifacts and the console output is 4096 characters.

I do not get any errors.

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

char *user_input();

int main() {


    char *x = user_input();

    printf("%s", x);
    
    return 0;
}

char *user_input() {

    const int block_size = 200;
    size_t temp_str_size, general_str_size = 0;
    char buffer[block_size];

    //allocates memory
    char *input = malloc(block_size * sizeof(char));

    do {

        //reads input to buffer
        if (fgets(buffer, block_size, stdin) != NULL) {


            temp_str_size = strlen(buffer);

            //reallocates whatever memory is needed for input 
            realloc(input, temp_str_size + general_str_size);
            
            //null check
            if (input == NULL) {
                printf("Unable to reallocate memory\n");
                return NULL;
            }
            
            
            strcat(input, buffer); // probably problem occurs here 

            // increases general string size for expanding memory reallocation
            general_str_size += temp_str_size;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
        
        
    } while (temp_str_size == block_size - 1);
    return input;
}
```

Comment: `strcat(input, buffer)` both params need to contain strings. `input` content is unintialised. Init with `input[0] = '\0'` after `malloc`.

Comment: It helped with artifacts at the beginning! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcat(input, buffer)` both params need to contain strings. `input` content is unintialised and hence has indeterminate values. Initialise with `input[0] = '\0'` after `malloc`.

Comment: This also explains the UB difference on different OSes.